# Is there a theory of transcendental functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, reference-request

Lately I've been interested in transcendental functions but as I tried to search for books or articles on the theory of transcendental functions, I only obtained irrelevant results (like calculus books or special functions). On the other hand, there's many books and articles on algebraic functions like:

- [Algebraic Function Fields and Codes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540768777)
- [Topics in the Theory of Algebraic Function Fields](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817671196)
- [Introduction to Algebraic and Abelian Functions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387907106)

Are there any references for the theory of transcendental functions? Did anyone studied rigorously such functions or is this field of mathematics outside the reach of contemporary mathematics?

Comment: maybe you could give some examples of transcendental functions and what abou them is interesting. also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions

Comment: At the risk of displaying my own ignorance: What do you mean by "transcendental function"?  Any function that's not algebraic? That would include all sorts of wildness. Of not that then what _do_ you mean?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function

Comment: @WillJagy For example let $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}a_nx^n$. Give a necessary and sufficient condition on the sequence $(a_n)$ so that $f$ is a transcendental function. I mean such type of questions.

Comment: "an analytic function that does not satisfy a polynomial equation", fine. There are many many references on analytic functions, typically in texts on complex analysis. Most of them are transcendental.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_special_functions_and_eponyms

Answer (score 2):

The class of **all** functions is just too wild to study in general, so usually we focus on studying large collections of functions that still have certain nice properties. For example: algebraic, continuous, differentiable, Borel, measurable, . . .

"Transcendental" just means "anything not algebraic," so that's too broad. But there are many subclasses of transcendental functions which are nice: most continuous functions, for example, are transcendental, and we might say that calculus is the study of continuous functions.

But that's sort of dodging the point. One question we could ask is: do transcendental functions have any nice *algebraic* properties? That is, if what we care about is abstract algebra, are the algebraic functions really the only ones we can talk about? The answer is a resounding **no**, although things rapidly get hard, and I don't know much here. I do know that some classes of transcendental *numbers* have rich algebraic structure theory - see [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/galois.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/galois.pdf), or [http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/TranscendencePeriods.pdf](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Emichel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/TranscendencePeriods.pdf).

Comment: Of course we could study differentiable (or maybe analytic) transcendental functions but did anyone study it?

Comment: `"Transcendental" just means "anything not algebraic," so that's too broad`. Couldn't we apply the same reasoning to numbers?

Comment: We do. That's why we study specific sets of numbers instead of the abstract idea of numbers

Answer (score 1):

A transcendental function is any function that is not algebraic.  That's about all you can say about them in general.  Of course there are specific classes of transcendental functions that do have interesting theories.

Comment: I know some examples of transcendental functions but do you mean by "classes of transcendental functions"?

Comment: For example, the class of functions you can get starting with the constant functions, the identity function, *and $e^x$,* and closing under multiplication, quotient, addition, composition. If we didn't include $e^x$, we'd just get the rational functions; when we do include $e^x$, we get a class of functions which are "rational relative to $e^x$," whatever that means. They include lots of transcendental functions (like $e^x$), but still have some very nice properties.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I got your point but that's too restricted. It's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @metacompactness Well, what are you looking for?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Some example: let $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}a_nx^n$. Give a necessary and sufficient condition on the sequence $(a_n)$ so that $f$ is a transcendental function. What are the transcendental functions whose derivative is algebraic? Let $f$ be an algebraic function and $\alpha\in\Bbb{R}$, what condition should we impose on $\alpha$ so that $\frac{d^{\alpha}}{dx^{\alpha}}f(x)$ is transcendental... I have a feeling that every question about transcendental functions is an open question.